# Odd image loading in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to improve my bootstrap carousel by using divs with a background image rather than just an ordinary image. Background images are much more flexible and easier to use, but I'm having issues with the images. Once a new slide comes, there is no image but after a second it appears.

If you click the buttons, it looks like the next image is empty but then it suddenly appears. Any ideas on how i can fix this?

Comment: How does using a background image improve the carousel? Seems like your just adding more code to the page and making things more difficult for yourself - and poteltially the user.

Answer (score 0):

This will always happen as background images are slower to load, either increase your server or change the image to a normal image what is it that you are trying to do which requires a background image?

Comment: *"background images are slower to load"* How? Why? This is not true.

Comment: The page calls appon them later

Comment: So they're not slower to load. In any case, you're wrong. They're loaded in the order they are called in the code.

Comment: in the bootstrap carousell they are because it checks for a image to display before the background image hense the slight white pause

Comment: Right. So why not load the images in asynchronously before the carousel tries itself?

Comment: Why not suggest that then.

Answer (score 0):

You should asynchronously load the images before the carousel tries itself. There are a few ways to do this, but I would use some javascript as follows;

```
<script>
    var img = new Image(),
    url = "myimg.jpg",
    container = document.getElementById("holder-div");

    img.onload = function () { container.appendChild(img); };
    img.src = url;
</script>
```

You can do this for each image you need to be loaded before the carousel displays them.